# Proof of Fermat's Theorem for a Local Minimum

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, solution-verification

Fermat's Theorem for Local Extrema states that if a function $f(x)$ has a local extremum at $c$ and $f'(c)$ exists, then $f'(c)=0$.

I saw a textbook proof for the local maximum case that used the definition of a derivative and some inequalities. Most calculus textbooks I have seen prove this case that way and leave the proof of a local minimum as an exercise or vice versa. I will omit the local maximum proof myself as I want to get straight to the point.

I'm curious if the following logic works. We will assume the local maximum case as true.

Define a new function $g(x)=-(f(x))$. We will assume a critical point $c$ such that $f(c)$ is a local maximum. We want to first show that $g(c)$ is a local minimum. By the definition of $g(x)$, each $x \in D(f) \in D(g)$ where $D(f)$ and $D(g)$ are the domains of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ respectively. All to do to find $g(x)$ is negate $f(x)$ for any $x \in D(f)$. What this does in essence is it reflects the point $(x,f(x))$ across the x-axis to give you $(x,g(x))$. When a local or absolute extreme value gets reflected across the axis, it becomes the other type of extreme value. So if $f(c)$ is a local maximum at $x=c$, $g(c)$ is a local minimum at $x=c$.

Since Fermat's Theorem assumes $f'(c)$ exists, $g'(c)$ must also exist since negating an existing value won't make it nonexistent. Since $f(x)$ is differentiable at $x=c$ and $g(x)$ can be thought of as $(-1)*f(x)$, we can use the Product Rule and $g'(c)=(-1)(f'(c))*(0)(f(c))=(-1)(0)*(0)=0*0=0$. Thus $g'(c)=0$ and the case for the local minimum has been proven.

**QED**

Is that a good rigorous proof for the local minimum case given the local maximum case? Thanks.

Comment: Yes. The local-max case follows easily from the local-min case. You may sometimes see "WLOG" ("without loss of generality"), E.g. "WLOG let f have a local min at c" in a proof that f'(c)=0, meaning that the reader is expected to see how one case implies every other case.

Comment: Sorry if the title confused you. I meant for the title to say "Local Minimum". I don't know if that confused you.

Answer (score -1):

It is unclear what you are proving. If you wan't to prove the local minimum case, you should start with a function $g \colon (a, b) \to \mathbb{R}$ with a local minimum at $c \in (a, b)$, and then show that $g'(c) = 0$. The idea is to show that $-g$ has a local maximum at $c$. Your argument is probably okay for a causal reader, but is not rigorous. A rigorous algebraic argument is not difficult here. We have $g(c) \leq g(x)$ for $x$ near $c$. Thus $-g(c) \geq -g(x)$ for $x$ near $c$, so $-g$ has a local maximum at $c$. Thus as you said, $g'(c) = -(-g)'(c) = -0 = 0$.

Comment: I meant for the title to be "Local Minimum". Sorry if that confused you.